# SQL Server - Linked Server - Using OPENROWSET with windows integrated security

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, security, linked-server, openrowset

I have seen many articles regarding OPENROWSET using integrated security (Windows Authentication), but I could not make it work for me.

It is working fine using SQL Server authentication:

```
 select *
 FROM
 OPENROWSET('SQLOLEDB',
 'myserver';'monitor';'#J4g4nn4th4#',
 'SELECT GETDATE() AS [RADHE]')
```

But the same query I am trying to run using windows authentication, and it is not working:

```
select *
 FROM
 OPENROWSET('SQLOLEDB',
'myserver';'Integrated Security=SSPI',
 'SELECT GETDATE() AS [RADHE]')
```

Can someone please post an example that works?

[Here is a good article](http://www.theboreddba.com/Categories/miscellaneous/Using-OPENROWSET-instead-of-a-Linked-Server.aspx) that describes OPENROWSET usage.

**Examples of working scripts using OPENROWSET - please read comments**

```
 ----------------------------------------------------------------
 -- this works - linked server REPLON1
 ----------------------------------------------------------------

select *
 FROM
 OPENROWSET('SQLOLEDB',
'Server=REPLON1;Trusted_Connection=yes;',
 'SELECT GETDATE() AS [RADHE]')

 select *
 FROM
 OPENROWSET('SQLOLEDB',
'Server=REPLON1;Trusted_Connection=yes;',
 'SET FMTONLY OFF select * from sys.dm_exec_requests')


 SELECT a.*
FROM OPENROWSET('SQLOLEDB', 'server=replon1;Trusted_Connection=yes;', 'SET
FMTONLY OFF select * from sys.dm_exec_requests') AS a
WHERE a.session_id > 50
ORDER BY a.start_time desc



  ----------------------------------------------------------------
 -- this does not work - when using windows authentication
 -- apparently because windows server 2003 and windows server 2012 have problems connecting - related to SID
 -- it works fine using SQL Server Authentication
 ----------------------------------------------------------------

 select *
 FROM
 OPENROWSET('SQLOLEDB',
'Server=SQLREPLON1\REP;Trusted_Connection=yes;',
 'SELECT GETDATE() AS [RADHE]')

-- Msg 18456, Level 14, State 1, Line 1
--Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'.



 ----------------------------------------------------------------
 -- this works - linked server SQLREPLON1\REP
 ----------------------------------------------------------------

 select *
 FROM
 OPENROWSET('SQLOLEDB',
 'SQLREPLON1\REP';'monitor';'#J4g4nn4th4#',
 'SELECT * from SAReporting.DBO.tblStockLedgerMovement')
```

Comment: Error you are facing ?

Comment: So what happens if you use the first query in the article you have linked to? `select a.* from openrowset('SQLNCLI', 'Server=myserver;Trusted_Connection=yes;', 'SELECT GETDATE() AS [RADHE]') as a`

Comment: @MikaelEriksson Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'.

Comment: I guess you have got the typical problem with Kerberos: double hop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Declare variable to get current instance name and pass value to `OpenROWSet`.

**Enable Ad Hoc Distributed Queries**

```
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
RECONFIGURE
GO
EXEC sp_configure 'ad hoc distributed queries', 1
RECONFIGURE
GO
```

**OPENROWSET using windows authentication to fetch data**

```
DECLARE @InstanceName VARCHAR(200),
    @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT  @InstanceName = ( SELECT @@servername  )


SELECT  @sql = 'select a.* from openrowset(''SQLNCLI'', ''Server='
        + @InstanceName
        + ';Trusted_Connection=yes;'', ''select * from Databasename.dbo.TableName'') as a'

EXEC sp_executeSQL @sql
```

Answer (score 1):

This is for DBAs out there who are using OPENROWSET to collect data from multiple instances. I also found a new method.

Try to execute following before your script

```
execute as login = 'sa'
GO
```

so your full script would look like

```
execute as login = 'sa'
GO

select *
 FROM
 OPENROWSET('SQLOLEDB',
'Server=SQLREPLON1\REP;Trusted_Connection=yes;',
 'SELECT GETDATE() AS [RADHE]')
```

You will need sysadmin or IMPERSONATE ANY LOGIN privileges for this to work.

Disclaimer:

if you are executing from Query Window it will work. If you are running from a job, you need to make sa job owner. This might also need more steps involving SQL Server service account, SPN configuration but I have not tested it yet.